# Pass a record from object to salesforce community

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, object, js, component

I created this object containing FAQs.
Later I created a lwc component that should pass me the FAQ in this object in my community, but rightly if in "getRecord" I put "$ recordId" it doesn't take it automatically, but I have to statically insert the id of the record and this is not good since the further you go, the more FAQs there will be in the community.

JS File

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import DOMANDA_FAQ from '@salesforce/schema/EI_FAQ__c.Domanda__c';
import RISPOSTA_FAQ from '@salesforce/schema/EI_FAQ__c.Risposta__c';

const _FIELDS = [DOMANDA_FAQ, RISPOSTA_FAQ];

export default class Provadefinitiv extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: _FIELDS })
    EI_FAQ__c;

    get domanda() {
        return getFieldValue(this.EI_FAQ__c.data, DOMANDA_FAQ);
    }

    get risposta() {
        return getFieldValue(this.EI_FAQ__c.data, RISPOSTA_FAQ);
    }
}
```

HTML FILE

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Domanda: {domanda}</p>
        <p>Risposta: {risposta}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

I want to view all records of this object in a community page.

[image]

Comment: On which pages exactly do you want to use this LWC? Is there a direct relationship between these pages and the recordIds? I assume you're aware of how to [wire recordIds to pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_record_context)?

Comment: I'm trying to add the component in a custom page created by me, basically I would like to see all the records that are included in my object created in that community page, maybe wrong method .. I'm getting into it now.

Do you have any solution?